# Undefined variable: view after switch/case block

Tags: php

**Undefined variable: view in C:\xampp\htdocs\simabes\index.php on line 24**
*Undefined variable: view in*

> include $view;

```
<?php
include "inc/koneksi.php";
include "inc/konf.php";
include ("katalog/header.php");

$mod = isset($_GET['mod']);
    switch($mod){
        case "catalog" :
        $view = "katalog/katalog.php";
        break;
        case "info" :
        $view = "katalog/info.php";
        break;
        case "help" :
        $view = "katalog/bantuan.php";
        break;
        case "user" :
        $view = "katalog/pengguna.php";
        break;
        case "about" :
        $view = "katalog/tentang.php";
        break;
}
    include $view;
if(empty($mod)){
    include ("katalog/katalog.php");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated elsewhere you need a default value for your $mod variable.

However simply testing for the existence of a value assigned to the variable is not enough. Here's a ternary null coalescing version of the variable test.

```
$mod = $_GET['mod'] ?? 'catalog';
```

But this sets a value for $mod which could be incorrect and produce a different error later on. If someone enters a space or another character or anything other than what you expected in your switch list then $mod will be assigned an incorrect value and $view will never be assigned a value.

Every switch list should have a default value at the end.

I would suggest modifying your code as such:

```
<?php
include "inc/koneksi.php";
include "inc/konf.php";
include ("katalog/header.php");

    $mod = $_GET['mod'] ?? 'catalog';

    switch($mod) {
        case "info" :
            $view = "katalog/info.php";
            break;
        case "help" :
            $view = "katalog/bantuan.php";
            break;
        case "user" :
            $view = "katalog/pengguna.php";
            break;
        case "about" :
            $view = "katalog/tentang.php";
            break;
        default :
            $view = "katalog/katalog.php";
            break;
    }
    include $view;
    include $mod;
```

Answer (score 0):

because there is no default value for variable $mod if $_GET['mod'] is empty, try bellow code, it should work.

```
<?php
include "inc/koneksi.php";
include "inc/konf.php";
include ("katalog/header.php");

    $mod = isset($_GET['mod']) ? $_GET['mod'] : 'catalog';
    switch($mod) {
        case "catalog" :
        $view = "katalog/katalog.php";
        break;
        case "info" :
        $view = "katalog/info.php";
        break;
        case "help" :
        $view = "katalog/bantuan.php";
        break;
        case "user" :
        $view = "katalog/pengguna.php";
        break;
        case "about" :
        $view = "katalog/tentang.php";
        break;
    }
    include $view;
    include $mod;
```